# standard scaling data before when using spectral biclustering in scikit learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

Hej,

I have a dataset from different cohorts and I want to bicluster them with the [sklearn function Spectral Biclustering](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.bicluster.SpectralBiclustering.html#sklearn.cluster.bicluster.SpectralBiclustering).
As you can see in the link above this approach is using a kind of normalization to calculate the SVD.

**Is it necessary to normalize the data before biclustering, eg with [StandardScaling](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html) (zero mean and std of one)?** Because the function above still uses a kind of normalization. 
**Is that enough or do I have to normalise them before, eg when the data is coming from different distributions?**

I am getting different results with and without standardscaling and I can not find information in the [original paper](https://static.aminer.org/pdf/PDF/000/303/275/global_biclustering_of_microarray_data.pdf) if it is necessary or not.

You can find the code and an example of my [dataset](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3tu4ayxxre3izvl/raw_data_biclustering.csv?dl=0). This is real data so I do not know the truth. I calculated at the end the [consensus score](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/bicluster/plot_spectral_biclustering.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-bicluster-plot-spectral-biclustering-py) to compare the 2 biclusters. Unfortunately the clusters are not the same.

I tried it also with artificial data (see example last link) and here the results are the same, but not with the real data.

**So how do I know which approach is the right one?**

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

from sklearn.cluster.bicluster import SpectralBiclustering
from sklearn.metrics import consensus_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

n_clusters = (4, 4)

data_org = pd.read_csv('raw_data_biclustering.csv', sep=',', index_col=0) 


# scale data & transform to dataframe
data_scaled = StandardScaler().fit_transform(data_org)
data_scaled = pd.DataFrame(data_scaled, columns=data_org.columns, index=data_org.index)


# plot original clusters
plt.imshow(data_scaled, aspect='auto', vmin=-3, vmax=5)
plt.title("Original dataset")
plt.show()


data_type = ['none_scaled', 'scaled']
data_all = [data_org, data_scaled]

models_all = []

for name, data in zip(data_type,data_all):

    # spectral biclustering on the shuffled dataset
    model = SpectralBiclustering(n_clusters=n_clusters, method='bistochastic'
                                         , svd_method='randomized', n_jobs=-1
                                         , random_state=0
                                         )
    model.fit(data)


    newOrder_row = [list(r) for r in zip(model.row_labels_, data.index)]
    newOrder_row.sort(key=lambda k: (k[0], k[1]), reverse=False)
    order_row = [i[1] for i in newOrder_row]

    newOrder_col = [list(c) for c in zip(model.column_labels_, [int(x) for x in data.keys()])]
    newOrder_col.sort(key=lambda k: (k[0], k[1]), reverse=False)
    order_col = [i[1] for i in newOrder_col]

    # reorder the data matrix
    X_plot = data_scaled.copy()
    X_plot = X_plot.reindex(order_row) # rows
    X_plot = X_plot[[str(x) for x in order_col]] # columns

    # use clustermap without clustering
    cm=sns.clustermap(X_plot, method=None, metric=None, cmap='viridis'
                  ,row_cluster=False, row_colors=None
                  , col_cluster=False, col_colors=None
                  , yticklabels=1, xticklabels=1
                  , standard_scale=None, z_score=None, robust=False
                  , vmin=-3, vmax=5
                  ) 

    ax = cm.ax_heatmap

    # set labelsize smaller
    cm_ax = plt.gcf().axes[-2]
    cm_ax.tick_params(labelsize=5.5)


    # plot lines for the different clusters
    hor_lines = [sum(item) for item in model.biclusters_[0]]
    hor_lines = list(np.cumsum(hor_lines[::n_clusters[1]]))

    ver_lines = [sum(item) for item in model.biclusters_[1]]
    ver_lines = list(np.cumsum(ver_lines[:n_clusters[0]]))

    for pp in range(len(hor_lines)-1):
        cm.ax_heatmap.hlines(hor_lines[pp],0,X_plot.shape[1], colors='r')

    for pp in range(len(ver_lines)-1):
        cm.ax_heatmap.vlines(ver_lines[pp],0,X_plot.shape[0], colors='r')

    # title
    title = name+' - '+str(n_clusters[1])+'-'+str(n_clusters[0])
    plt.title(title)
    cm.savefig(title,dpi=300)
    plt.show() 

    # save models
    models_all.append(model)

# compare models    
score = consensus_score(models_all[0].biclusters_, models_all[1].biclusters_)
print("consensus score between: {:.1f}".format(score))
```

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: I am not sure if the large screen shots help. I think you should at least (also) include some of your code here.

Comment: I changed it to more simple and with own data and code